# Zend DB where clause error

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, zend-db

EDIT:

**$query->where('`value` = ?', $number);** 
It seems that does the job. I still don't know why it won't work under normal conditions, but it's a work around.. still looking for the right answer!

---

I'm trying to query a DB with a simple:

```
$number = 4;
$query = $this->select();
$query->where('value = ?', $number);
$row = $this->fetchRow($query);
```

But for some reason I constantly got this error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'value = 4)
>   LIMIT 1' at line 1

When I do my assemble to see the query string:

```
SELECT `mighty_table`.* FROM `mighty_table` WHERE (value = 4)
```

My column name its not escaped..

Should Zend DB do that? :| It's strange since i use this same method in other projects and it always works..

Comment: `Syntax error or access violation` Check you have your connection string correct. This could be caused by a wrong username/password.

Comment: @vascowhite got my connection working, thats not the problem. :\

Comment: try `$query->where("value = '?', $number);`. I can't see anything else that could be wrong.

Comment: do you have a mighty_table.value column in your db?

Comment: If you run the query in your database directly does it work?

Comment: @vascowhite Yes, I have that column but your idea don't work either..

Comment: @TimFountain No, it doesnt work.. thats why i dont get it.. but i use the same method in another function, using the same table, and it works..

Comment: Will the query work if you remove the where() statement?

Comment: I take it this is in a class that extends Zend_Db_Table? Could you post the code for the class?

Comment: Look at Mona Cheikhna'a answer and heed it, `select()` will handle normal qoutes but will not automatically quote Mysql keywords,identfiers,reserved words. You need to use `->quoteIdentifier()` if you want a column named `value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"value" is indeed a reserved word in MySQL. As a result you need to escape it using back ticks.

I would expect this to work:

```
$fieldName = $this->getAdapter()->quoteIdentifier('value');
$query->where($fieldName = ?", $number);
```

Answer (score 3):

[From zend manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.html) :

> Note: The values and identifiers in the SQL expression are not quoted
>   for you. If you have values or identifiers that require quoting, you
>   are responsible for doing this. Use the quote(), quoteInto(), and
>   quoteIdentifier() methods of the database adapter.

So for example you can use quoteInto :

```
$number = 4;
$query = $this->select();
$where = $this->getAdapter()->quoteInto('value = ?', $number);
$query->where($where);
$row = $this->fetchRow($query);
```

Comment: This one will probably need to be ->quoteIdentifier(), I'm pretty sure that VALUE is a keyword in Mysql, I know that VALUES is.

Comment: That's in fact the reason why my code was all buggy. Thanks for the answer! :)